# get all columns of 2 related models in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get all the fields of Services and Suppliers as querySet in view

```
class supplierMaster(models.Model):
    supplierId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    supplierName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    status = models.ForeignKey(statusMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplierName

class servicesMaster(models.Model):
    serviceId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    serviceName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    supplierId = models.ForeignKey(supplierMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(statusMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.serviceName
```

views.py:

```
def dashboard(request): 
    myservice = servicesMaster.objects.select_related('serviceName','supplierName').all() 

    return render(request, 'testing.html', { 'myservice': myservice, })
```

Comment: Share your code, What have you already tried?

Comment: def dashboard(request):



    myservice = servicesMaster.objects.select_related('serviceName','supplierName').all()
    return render(request, 'testing.html', {
        'myservice': myservice,
    })